# Can i visualise react native views at run time like android studio

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

I use hot reloading for visualise my view on react native app. This is not cool. What if i can see my view at edit time. So that i don't need to see that in emulator.

Currently i am using visual studio code for react native development. 
Is there some extension that provide run time view like Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few options that might get you what you want:

1. Turn on Hot Reloading in your simulator/device to see changes as you develop them.
2. Use something like [React Native Storybook](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/tree/master/app/react-native) to develop components in isolation
3. Use a WYSIWYG tools like [BuilderX](https://builderx.io/) to develop your app.

Comment: Thanks bro you told me 2 very useful tools.